# ¿Cómo hago una herramienta que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo, en segundo plano y que inicie cuando el equipo se encienda? Similiar a un proceso

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows, procesos-en-segundo-plano

Necesito hacer una herramienta en C# que me envíe datos a un web service y que la misma pueda **ejecutarse cada cierto tiempo, en segundo plano y que inicie cuando el equipo se encienda.**

Estoy en un trabajo que consiste que pueda reconocer el nombre de un proceso de cualquier máquina y notificar que el proceso se cerró, en mi caso podíamos escoger la herramienta y escogí OneDrive.

Entonces mi idea fue hacer lo siguiente:

1. Un WebService que reciba el nombre de equipo, si está conectado o no y que lo envíe a una base de datos.
2. Una herramienta que se encargue unicamente de enviar el nombre de equipo y si encontró o no el proceso corriendo. De momento hice un Windows Form que con darle click a un botón hace el proceso de reconocer si el proceso está corriendo o no, lo cual trabaja bien **pero me hace falta que la herramienta se ejecute cada cierto tiempo, que trabaje en segundo plano y que inicie cuando la máquina encienda.**

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar, saludos.

Comment: necesitas un servicio de windows.. es lo que hiciste, pero ahora instalalo como servicio ;)

Comment: No podrías utilizar una tarea programada?

Comment: Puedes crear un servicio, como comentan, pero ya no sería winforms (a menos que hagas dos proyectos). La otra opción es que hagas un proyecto winforms y configures windows para que inicie esa aplicación, pero solo iniciaría cuando el usuario inicie sesión, no al encenderse el equipo.

Comment: Si, lo mejor es que hagas un servicio y lo configures para que inicie al arrancar el pc (como dice Luis, más que al arrancar el pc, al iniciar sesión). Además lo de hacer una tarea cada x segundos lo puedes resolver con un Timer, eso es muy sencillo.

Comment: tengo entendido que windows  tiene algo como `Task Scheduler windows`  donde puedes agregar tus script para ejecutar lo hice algun tiempo pero no recuerdo como

Comment: consulta windows services https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280496/what-are-the-best-practices-when-running-a-process-as-a-windows-service

Comment: Puedes utilizar UnityQuartzJob, un robot que se ejecuta por detrás de la aplicación en la cual  le puedes setear en el horario que deseas por medio de cronExpressions.

Answer (score -1):

para que tu algoritmo inicie con la pc podrias implementar esto en tu codigo:
PD: se necesita ejecutar como administrador

```
private void IniciarConWindows() //Iniciar con windows
    {
        string nombre = Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        string ruta = Path.GetFullPath(nombre);
        try
        {
            if (configuracion.iniciarConWindows)
            {
                Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", true).SetValue(ruta, nombre);
            }
            else
            {
                Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", true).DeleteValue(ruta, false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error al configurar");
        }
    }
```

Para que la tarea se ejecute cada cierto tiempo, podrias utilizar un timer, hay varios timers que se pueden usar en c#, investiga cual es el mas conveniente para tu proyecto, pero de todas formas te dejo un ejemplo de uno asyncronico

```
private static System.Timers.Timer temporizadorPing;
        temporizadorPing = new System.Timers.Timer(300000) { AutoReset = true, Enabled = true };
        temporizadorPing.Elapsed += FuncionQueQuieroEjecutar;
        temporizadorPing.Start();
```

Con estos argumentos deberia quedar tu funcion a ejecutar por el timer:

```
 void FuncionQueQuieroEjecutar(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

Para que se ejecute en 'segundo plano' podes enviar en winform a la bandeja de sistema, asi no estarias viendo el icono en tu barra de tareas
Para esto investiga sobre el componente **NotifyIcon**

Comment: Pero así no se ejecutaría al inicio de Windows, cuando aun no inicia sesión el usuario.

Comment: Hay procesos que se ejecuten antes que una persona inicie session y que no sean de microsoft?

Comment: si, los servicios de windows, por ejemplo el antivirus